# Theorem 9.12 Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

**9.11 Definition** Suppose  is an open set in $^{n}$, f maps  into $^{m}$, and $x ∈$. If there exists a linear transformation  of $^{n}$ into $^{m}$ such that
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\left|\mathbf{f(x +h)-f(x)-Ah}\right|}{|\mathbf{h}|}=0,\tag{14}$$

**9.12 Theorem** Suppose  and **f** are as in Definition 9.11, $x ∈$, and (14) holds with =1 and with =2. Then 1=2.

Here's Rudin's Proof

> If $\mathbf{B=A_1-A_2}$, the inequality$$\left|\mathbf{Bh}\right|\le\left|\mathbf{f(x+h)-f(x)-A_1h}\right|+\left|\mathbf{f(x+h)-f(x)-A_2h}\right|$$
>   shows that$\frac{|\mathbf{Bh}|}{|\mathbf{h}|}\to 0$ as $h\to 0$. For fixed $\mathbf{h\ne 0}$, it follows that
>   $$\frac{|\mathbf{B(th)}|}{|\mathbf{th}|}\to 0 \text{ as } t\to 0.\tag{16}$$
>   The linearity of  shows that the left side of (16) is independent of $t$. Thus $=0$ for every $∈R^{n}$. Hence $=0$.

My question is that why do we need the step involving t? Can we directly claim $B=0$ when we know $\frac{|\mathbf{Bh}|}{|\mathbf{h}|}\to 0$ as $h\to 0$? Could someone please give me a counterexample?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your definition seems incomplete. You seem to be describing differentiation , but no-where in the definition is it said what you are defining.

Comment: $\sin(x) / x \to 1$ for $x \to 0$.

Comment: The proof ends once $B$ is proven to be the zero transformation. Well, maybe even not then, but when $A_1$ is shown to be equal to $A_2$, but Rudin probably assumes that his readers know how to get from $B=0$ to $A_1=A_2$. So, one must get to show that $\forall h,\ Bh=0$. The statement $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|Bh|}{|h|}=0$, is a different statement, even if eventually it implies the other one. The proof's job is to show how that implication goes.

Comment: To me this seems very direct - you know the behaviour of $B$ for small $h$, and you need to reason about its behaviour for big $h$, which you can get by the scaling property - small $h$ are just scalings of big $h$, and linear maps scale linearly. What would you consider to be more direct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can claim that only when $B$ is linear, as per the explanation. If $B$ is not linear that is not true, with a simple example when $B(h)=(h^2,0,.....,0)$. Then:

$$ \dfrac{\vert B(h)\vert}{\vert h\vert}=\frac{\vert (h^2,0,.....,0) \vert}{\vert h \vert} = \vert(h,0,...,0)\vert =h \rightarrow 0$$

But $B(x)\neq 0$ for all fixed $x\neq 0$.

Comment: but here $B=A_{1}-A_{2}$, which is also linear transformation, so we can claim $B=0$ in this case?

Comment: Well it is true, but doesn't seem trivial. You always have that when $\frac{\vert B(h) \vert}{\vert h\vert}\rightarrow 0$ and $B$ is linear, then $B=0$. But the majority of the proof (although short) is showing exactly this claim.

Answer (score 2):

You want to show that $B=0$ which means that you need to prove that $Bh=0$ for $\textit{all possible values of}\ h$.

You know that $\frac{Bh}{h}\to 0$. Now, let $h_0\neq 0$ be a fixed but arbitrary vector. Then,  $\frac{B(th_0)}{th_0}\to 0$ as $t\to 0$ simply because as $t\to 0,\ th_0\to 0.$

Now, linearity of $B$ implies that $\frac{B(th_0)}{th_0}=\frac{Bh_0}{h_0}\to 0$. But $\frac{Bh_0}{h_0}$ is $\textit{constant}$, so in fact $\frac{Bh_0}{h_0}=0$ and since $h_0\neq 0$ it must be that $Bh_0=0$. Therefore, $B$ is the zero transformation.

Comment: I understand this, I just want to know why we need the step involving t rather than claim $B=0$ when we know $\frac{Bh}{h}\to 0$

Comment: Because, as pointed out in other answer, the fact that the quotient approaches zero does not imply that the numerator is $identically$ zero for all $h$. The fact that $B$ is linear is what makes the proof work. So you need to use this fact somewhere right?